# calculate multiple input value in javascript

Tags: javascript, math, calculation

I have 5 input fields (range sliders) and I'm trying to return a result when any of the input values changes. 
The problem is "value4" is used 2 times in the equation and this is causing the problem. If I change "value4" my result does not change.

```
      function output(){
      var value1 = document.getElementById('NumberOfEmployees_input').value;
      var value2 = document.getElementById('AverageSalary_input').value;
      var value3 = document.getElementById('AverageTime_input').value;
      var value4 = document.getElementById('WorkdaysWeek_input').value;
      var value5 = document.getElementById('AccountingHours_input').value;

      document.getElementById('saving').innerHTML =
          (((parseInt(value1) * parseInt(value2))/(parseInt(value4) * parseInt(1920))) * (parseInt(value3) * parseInt(value4) * parseInt(48)))
          + (parseInt(value5) * parseInt(13500)) - parseInt(183600);
  }
```

Can anybody give me a hint?
Thank you!

Comment: `value4` cancels out in your equation. You can opt to use it 0 times. Save the case where `value4 = 0`.

Comment: This was the case. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation can be simplified, you added too many brackets (I removed the `parseInt()` function to make it more readable).

[image]

It is equivalent to:

[image]

`value4` is canceled:

[image]

You may have made an error in your equation.

Comment: You got there faster than me, with tex too. :P Nice.

Comment: @cusmar you are right. I made an error in my equation. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The code is very difficult to read. I suggest simplifying the code by first, shortening the variable names. Then apply `parseInt` at an early stage to reduce clutter afterwards. 
Plus, there is no need to `parseInt(123)` since `123` is already Integer.

```
function output(){
  var v1 = parseInt(document.getElementById('NumberOfEmployees_input').value);
  var v2 = parseInt(document.getElementById('AverageSalary_input').value);
  var v3 = parseInt(document.getElementById('AverageTime_input').value);
  var v4 = parseInt(document.getElementById('WorkdaysWeek_input').value);
  var v5 = parseInt(document.getElementById('AccountingHours_input').value);

  var n = v1 * v2;  // nominator
  var d = v4 * 1920 * v3 * v4 * 48;  // denominator

  document.getElementById('saving').innerHTML = (n/d) + (v5 * 13500) - 183600;

}
```

Comment: I agree the parentheses are a mess. Moreover, "the code is difficult to read" speaks for itself by confusing your numerators and denominators. : )

Answer (score 1):

Here is your equation

```
(
 (
  (parseInt(value1) * parseInt(value2))
   /
  (parseInt(value4) * parseInt(1920))
 ) *
 (parseInt(value3) * parseInt(value4) * parseInt(48))
)
+ (parseInt(value5) * parseInt(13500))
- parseInt(183600);

   v1 • v2
(-----------  • v3 • v4 • 48) + (v5 • 13500) - 183600
  v4 • 1920

//  valueN has been substituted with vN
```

By observation, `v4` cancels out.

This reduces your *chain of math* to

```
( (parseInt(value1)*parseInt(value2)*parseInt(value3)*48) / 1920 )
    + (parseInt(value5) * 13500)
    - 183600;
```

*Note that originally, `v4` = 0 would fail. This may or may not be intended.*

---

To make your code more readable you can separate the numerator and denominator as so

```
n = parseInt(value1) * parseInt(value2) * parseInt(value3) * 48
document.getElementById('saving').innerHTML = (n/1920) + (v5 * 13500) - 183600;
```

While this might not answer your question of using 2 input values, this provides a workaround in your situation. You didn't seem to realise this when you posted your question. Perhaps you misplaced a bracket or made an error in your calculations?

Comment: I made an error in simplifying my equation. Your answer is very useful and helped me refine my mess. Thank you!